# Local finality condition (for re-indexing parameterized colimits)

Tags: ct.category-theory, limits-and-colimits

I'm in need of a condition that is analogous to the "finality" condition in the following lemma:

Lemma: A functor $F\colon A\to B$ is final if and only if for any functor $x\colon B\to Set$, the natural map $colim (xF)\to colim(x)$ is an isomorphism.

This lemma could be taken instead as a definition of *final functor*, but finality is more easily recognized by whether all slice categories of a certain kind are non-empty and connected. I want a recognition principle for a more general kind of finality, which I'm calling local finality.

The more general context requires a bit of notation. If $A$ is a category, write $A-Set$ for the category of functors $A\to Set$. If $F\colon A\to B$ is a functor, write $\Delta_F\colon B-Set\to A-Set$ for the ``composition with $F$" functor, and write $\Sigma_F$ for its left adjoint and $\Pi_F$ for its right adjoint (these three are also sometimes denoted by $F^*, F_!$, and $F_*$ respectively).

The following lemma (obviously) holds for some appropriate definition of *locally final*.

Lemma: Suppose that we have a commutative diagram $A\xrightarrow{F}B\xrightarrow{x}C$ and let $G:=xF$. Then $F$ is locally final if and only if the natural map $\Sigma_G\Delta_F\to\Sigma_x$ is an isomorphism.

Is there a nice recognition principle for this kind of ``local finality"? I have a big messy condition obtained by following my nose, but it's of no use. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since nobody has said so, I will mention that the notion you describe is a particular case of the known --- but perhaps obscure --- concept of Guitart exact square. One can read about it in [the nlab page](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exact+square) and in [an article by Maltsiniotis](http://arxiv.org/abs/1101.4144). Even though the latter article aims to generalize exact squares to a homotopical context, it still gives a good, if somewhat skewed, overview of the concept.

To justify the relative usefulness of exact squares, let me state that instances of that notion characterize: fully faithful functors, (co)final functors, initial functors, absolute Kan extensions, among other concepts (including my personal favourite, [absolutely dense functors](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/8/n20/8-20abs.html)).

For completeness, I will summarize some characterizations of the notion of exact square. A square of small categories, functors, and natural transformations:
$$ \begin{matrix} 
A & \overset{U}{\longrightarrow} & B \\
\llap{\scriptstyle L}\Big\downarrow  & \big\Downarrow\rlap{\scriptstyle\alpha} & \Big\downarrow\rlap{\scriptstyle R} \\
A' & \underset{D}{\longrightarrow} & B'
\end{matrix} $$
(i.e. a natural transformation $\alpha:R\circ U\to D\circ L$) is called *exact* if any of the following equivalent conditions hold:

1. The natural 2-cell induced by $\alpha$ in
   $$ \begin{matrix} 
   \textrm{Set}^A & \overset{\Delta_U}{\longleftarrow} & \textrm{Set}^B \\
   \llap{\scriptstyle \Sigma_L}\Big\downarrow  & \big\Downarrow & \Big\downarrow\rlap{\scriptstyle \Sigma_R} \\
   \textrm{Set}^{\smash{A'}} & \underset{\Delta_D}{\longleftarrow} & \textrm{Set}^{\smash{B'}}
   \end{matrix} $$
   is an isomorphism. That is, the induced natural transformation $\Sigma_L\circ\Delta_U \to \Delta_D\circ\Sigma_R$ is an isomorphism.
2. For every $x\in A'$, the naturally induced functor on over-categories
   $$ A/x=L/x \longrightarrow R/(D(x))=B/(D(x)) $$
   is (co)final.
3. For every $x\in B$, the naturally induced functor on under-categories
   $$ x/A=x/U \longrightarrow (R(x))/D=(R(x))/A' $$
   is initial.
4. For each object $x\in B$ and $y\in A'$, and each arrow $f:R(x) \to D(y)$ in $B'$, the category of factorizations $C_{x,y,f}$ is connected (which I, Karol, and [a surprisingly large/vocal set of mathematicians](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/120536/is-the-empty-graph-a-tree) take to mean non-empty). Here, the category $C_{x,y,f}$ is defined by:

   - the objects of $C_{x,y,f}$ are triples $(z,g,h)$ where $z$ is an object of $A$, $g:x\to U(z)$ is a morphism in $B$, and $h:L(z)\to y$ is a morphism of $A'$, such that $D(h)\circ\alpha_z \circ R(g)=f$;
   - a morphism $(z,g,h)\to (z',g',h')$ in $C_{x,y,f}$ is an arrow $k:z\to z'$ such that $g'= U(k)\circ g$ and $h=h'\circ L(k)$.
5. For all objects $x\in B$ and $y\in A'$, the natural map from the coend
   $$ \int^{a\in A} B(x,U(a))\times A'(L(a),y) \longrightarrow B'(R(x),D(y)) $$
  is an isomorphism of sets.

Before proceeding, observe that condition 4 is simply a restatement of conditions 2 and 3. In fact, the categories of factorizations $C_{x,y,f}$ defined in 4 are exactly the categories whose connectedness must be checked to ensure that the functor in condition 2 is cofinal (respectively, that the functor in condition 3 is initial). More precisely, the categories $C_{x,y,f}$ are the under-categories $a/F$ of the functor $F$ in condition 2 (respectively, the over-categories of the functor in condition 3) for objects $a$ in the codomain of $F$. I feel this both motivates and gives a nice way to remember the definition of $C_{x,y,f}$.

Then $A\overset{F}{\rightarrow}B\overset{x}{\rightarrow}C$ is locally final (in the sense David Spivak states) if and only if the the square
$$ \begin{matrix} 
A & \overset{F}{\longrightarrow} & B \\
\llap{\scriptstyle G}\Big\downarrow  & \big\Downarrow\rlap{\scriptstyle\textrm{id}_G}\ & \Big\downarrow\rlap{\scriptstyle x} \\
C & \underset{\textrm{id}_C}{\longrightarrow} & C
\end{matrix} $$
(filled by the the identity 2-cell on $G=x\circ F$) is exact. Under this interpretation, condition 4 above is exactly the condition given in Karol Szumiło's answer.

**Addendum:** To finish off, here are a few further equivalent characterizations of the exactness of the original square ($\alpha:R\circ U\to D\circ L$) drawn at the top of this answer:

- For any cocomplete category X, the natural 2-cell induced by $\alpha$ in
  $$ \begin{matrix} 
  X^A & \overset{\Delta_U}{\longleftarrow} & X^B \\
  \llap{\scriptstyle \Sigma_L}\Big\downarrow  & \big\Downarrow & \Big\downarrow\rlap{\scriptstyle \Sigma_R} \\
  X^{\smash{A'}} & \underset{\Delta_D}{\longleftarrow} & X^{\smash{B'}}
  \end{matrix} $$
  is an isomorphism. Note that for $X=\textrm{Set}$, we recover condition 1 above.
- The natural 2-cell induced by $\alpha$ in
  $$ \begin{matrix} 
  \textrm{Set}^A & \overset{\Pi_U}{\longrightarrow} & \textrm{Set}^B \\
  \llap{\scriptstyle \Delta_L}\Big\uparrow  & \big\Uparrow & \Big\uparrow\rlap{\scriptstyle \Delta_R} \\
  \textrm{Set}^{\smash{A'}} & \underset{\Pi_D}{\longrightarrow} & \textrm{Set}^{\smash{B'}}
  \end{matrix} $$
  is an isomorphism.
- For any complete category X, the natural 2-cell induced by $\alpha$ in
  $$ \begin{matrix} 
  X^A & \overset{\Pi_U}{\longrightarrow} & X^B \\
  \llap{\scriptstyle \Delta_L}\Big\uparrow  & \big\Uparrow & \Big\uparrow\rlap{\scriptstyle \Delta_R} \\
  X^{\smash{A'}} & \underset{\Pi_D}{\longrightarrow} & X^{\smash{B'}}
  \end{matrix} $$
  is an isomorphism. Note that for $X=\textrm{Set}$, we recover the preceding condition.
- The opposite square
  $$ \begin{matrix} 
  A^{\textrm{op}} & \overset{L^{\textrm{op}}}{\longrightarrow} & {A'}^{\textrm{op}} \\
  \llap{\scriptstyle U^{\textrm{op}}}\Big\downarrow  & \big\Downarrow\rlap{\scriptstyle\alpha^{\textrm{op}}} & \Big\downarrow\rlap{\scriptstyle D^{\textrm{op}}} \\
  B^{\smash{\textrm{op}}} & \underset{R^{\textrm{op}}}{\longrightarrow} & {B'}^{\smash{\textrm{op}}}
  \end{matrix} $$
  is exact. Note that the preceding 3 conditions and condition 1 applied to this opposite square give diagrams with categories of presheaves (contravariant functors) on $A$, $B$, $A'$, and $B'$, instead of categories of covariant functors on those categories. In fact, a common (equivalent) definition of exactness is the analog of condition 1 for presheaves: the 2-cell in the square
  $$ \begin{matrix} 
  \widehat{A} & \overset{\Sigma_{U^{\textrm{op}}}}{\longrightarrow} & \widehat{B} \\
  \llap{\scriptstyle \Delta_{L^{\textrm{op}}}}\Big\uparrow  & \big\Downarrow\rlap{\scriptstyle} & \Big\uparrow\rlap{\scriptstyle \Delta_{R^{\textrm{op}}}} \\
  \widehat{A'} & \underset{\Sigma_{D^{\textrm{op}}}}{\longrightarrow} & \widehat{B'}
  \end{matrix} $$
  is an isomorphism.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Ricardo!

Comment: @David: I am happy to hear that. You are most welcome. By the way, I corrected a few errors in my answer: some arrows were pointing in the wrong direction and had the wrong names. I hope there are no major issues remaining.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you meant $\Sigma_G \Delta_F \to \Sigma_x$, otherwise this doesn't parse.

Here's my condition. It's not completely straightforward, but it is a generalization of the classical one you mentioned. I guess it's a matter of taste whether it's messy.

Consider a triple $(b, f, c)$ where $b$ is an object of $B$, $c$ is an object of $C$ and $f : x b \to c$ is a morphism in $C$. To each such triple one can associate a kind of "double slice", namely the "category of factorizations of $f$ through objects of the form $F a$". Its objects are triples $(g, a, h)$ where $a$ is an object of $A$, $g : b \to F a$ and $h : x F a \to c$ such that $h (x g) = f$. The morphisms are morphisms of $A$ making two evident triangles commute. My claim is that $\Sigma_G \Delta_F \to \Sigma_x$ is a natural isomorphism precisely when all such "categories of factorizations" are connected (which I take to include non-empty).

The argument is as follows. For any functor $W : A^\mathrm{op} \to \mathrm{Set}$ there is a $W$-weighted colimit functor $\mathrm{colim}^W : \mathrm{Set}^A \to \mathrm{Set}$ given by the coend formula $\mathrm{colim}^W Y = \int^{a \in A} Y_a \times W_a$ for $Y \in \mathrm{Set}^A$. A transformation $\phi : V \to W$ induces a transformation $\phi_* : \mathrm{colim}^V \to \mathrm{colim}^W$. It is easy to see that $\phi_*$ is an isomorphism if and only if $\phi$ is since we can recover $\phi$ form $\phi_*$ by evaluating it on representable functors.

We have formulas for Kan extensions via coends which say that $(\Sigma_x Y) c = \mathrm{colim}^{C(x -, c)} Y$ and similarly $(\Sigma_G \Delta_F Y)_c = \mathrm{colim}^{\int^a B(-, F a) \times C(x F a, c)} Y$ and the natural transformation in question is induced by the transformation $\int^a B(-, F a) \times C(x F a, c) \to C(x -, c)$ which takes a pair of morphisms $g : b \to F a$ and $h : x F a \to c$ and sends it to the composite $h (x g)$. We need to check that it is an isomorphism i.e. that the fiber over every point $f : x b \to c$ is a singleton. There is an explicit description of this coend as the quotient set of an equivalence relation and it yields a description of the fiber over $f$ as the quotient of the set of objects of the above "category of factorizations of $f$" by the relation which turns out to be the relation of being in the same component of this category.

Comment: Thanks Karol. I made the obvious edit to $\Sigma_G\Delta_F\to\Sigma_x$. I have another question, namely for conditions on $F$ whereby the map $\Delta_F\to\Delta_G\Sigma_x$ is an isomorphism. I'm going to try to adapt your technology to that situation.