# Connectedeness of toric varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, toric-varieties

Hi,

I would like to understand when a toric variety is connected. Given $\Delta$ a fan (possibly with infinitely many cones) in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n\geq 2$ denote with $X_{\Delta}$ the associated toric variety. I would like to know if there exists some property $P$ for which a theorem as follows holds:

if $\Delta$ satisfies $P$ then $X_{\Delta}$ is connected.

Comment: margarida? :) sei tu?

Comment: I don't even understand what it would mean for a disconnected variety to be toric. 

Comment: With the definition I know, every toric variety is connected.

Comment: The usual definition of "fan" implies that every two cone intersect in a common (non-empty) sub-cone: which implies that the open sets corresponding to those cones intersect in a non-empty open set. So the toric variety is connected by default. 

Comment: Wait... we will again have to discuss whether or not the empty scheme is connected.

Comment: Is there a good discussion of whether or not the empty scheme is connected somewhere?

Comment: @rghthndsd: I would not say it is a good discussion, but http://mathoverflow.net/questions/120536 contains what I was referring to.

Comment: @diverietti no @Dan Petersen, @Angelo I was just wondering whether one can exhibit $\coprod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}^1$ ($n$ could also be infinite) as toric variety not under the action of the obvious torus $\coprod_{i=1}^n\mathbb{G}_m$ but using $\mathbb{G}_m^r$, for some $r$ and a fan in some $\mathbb{R}^r$
@auniket thank you for the remark

Comment: Does $\coprod_{i=1}^n\mathbb{G}_m$ even admit a natural algebraic group structure? (Perhaps as $\mathbb{G}_m\times (\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z})$ but I'm not sure it's useful; and by the way it's not a torus, according to the usual definition of torus)