# Some kind of product of two 2d tensors to create a 3d tensor?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-theory, multilinear-algebra, tensor

I recently need to apply the following concept of product of two 2d tensors to create a 3d tensor (tensors understood as generalized arrays):
given two 2d tensors $A_{m\times n}$ and $B_{n\times p}$, we define the 3d tensor $C_{m\times n\times p}$ by
$$
C_{ijk}:=A_{ij}B_{jk}.
$$
Does anyone know what this product is called? Is there any public codebase in Python that implements this product for sparse tensors? Any reference is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This is an egregious misuse of the term "tensor". A tensor is not simply a generalized array, and your object $C_{ijk} $ is not a tensor as commonly understood.

Comment: This absolutely is a tensor, and a tensor [absolutely can be](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/286732/nonequivalent-definitions-in-mathematics/286767#comment743815_286767) a generalized array.

Comment: You could define the sparse tensor $H_a^{bc}$ which is 1 when $a=b=c$ and zero otherwise, and then it's just a tensor product followed by a contraction.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt this way of defining a tensor can also be found in the very beginning of the Definition section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor

Comment: @MinWu - you are pointing me to a wikipedia definition -  ok, let's go with that. The wikipedia definition you are pointing me to indeed explains that a tensor is not simply a generalized array, and a generalized array does not *define* a tensor. Rather, a tensor can be *represented* as a generalized array, in many different ways that are related by a transformation law. This transformation behavior is an important part of the definition of a tensor. It is the transformation behavior of your $C_{ijk} $ object that is the issue.